# Error while installing apache2 on Ubuntu 22.04 for Raspberry Pi: Following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have Ubuntu 22.04 server running on my Raspberry pi, was trying to install Apache2 but getting below error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/pendrive$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.5) but 2.4.57-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
           Recommends: ssl-cert but it is not going to be installed
```

Here is what I tried.

I uninstalled/purged (if any) versions of apache present on my system. Issue get update and upgrade command and then tried installing apache again but nothing worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)